# Wireshark doesn't show SSL packets with Python SSL sockets

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, wireshark

I followed [Python SSL socket echo test with self-signed certificate](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2013/1/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate) blog to test a simple SSL socket connection. I generated a self-signed certificate and I used the above Python code to just try that out.

Everything works as described but the problem is, I don't see any SSL traffic when I monitor network packets using Wireshark. All I see is just normal TCP packets but I'm expecting to see SSL protocol being used. Am I missing something?

For the sake of completeness I add the code:

**client.py**

```
import socket, ssl, pprint

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Require a certificate from the server. We used a self-signed certificate
# so here ca_certs must be the server certificate itself.
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                           ca_certs="server.crt",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)

ssl_sock.connect(('localhost', 10023))

print repr(ssl_sock.getpeername())
print ssl_sock.cipher()
print pprint.pformat(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

ssl_sock.write("boo!")

if False: # from the Python 2.7.3 docs
    # Set a simple HTTP request -- use httplib in actual code.
    ssl_sock.write("""GET / HTTP/1.0\r
    Host: www.verisign.com\n\n""")

    # Read a chunk of data.  Will not necessarily
    # read all the data returned by the server.
    data = ssl_sock.read()

    # note that closing the SSLSocket will also close the underlying socket
    ssl_sock.close()
```

**server.py**

```
import socket, ssl

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('', 10023))
bindsocket.listen(5)

def do_something(connstream, data):
    print "do_something:", data
    return False

def deal_with_client(connstream):
    data = connstream.read()
    while data:
        if not do_something(connstream, data):
            break
        data = connstream.read()

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="server.crt",
                                 keyfile="server.key")
    try:
        deal_with_client(connstream)
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

**Wireshark screenshot:**

[image: wireshark]

Comment: Does it still work (functionally) if you remove all the SSL from the client? E.g. are you sure it isn't just that Wireshark isn't reporting the use of SSL? E.g. Under 'protocol' I'd *expect* to see TCP, not SSL, as TCP is the network-layer protocol you're using.

Comment: @TomDalton, Wireshark reports SSL protocol if I just browse Google hence, I was expecting to see something similar. I'll remove SSL from client to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you won't see SSL/TLS is because you're using a different port than the standard 443. That's why Wireshark is unable to detect the protocol automatically. You have two options:

- Decode the traffic as SSL:

> Analyze > Decode As > Transport > SSL > Apply

- Add your port:

> Edit > Preferences > Protocols > HTTP > SSL/TLS Ports = 443, *{port}*